# MongoDB: Upsert a document and return updated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I m trying to run a query where I m trying to `upsert` a document using `findOneAndUpdate` in my backend Node JS api using mongodb-nodejs native driver. The problem I m facing is that, it is not returning the updated document and I m getting `null`, whenever the `upsert` is happening if no matching document is present.

I have already tried add `new` option but it doesn't seem to work with `findOneAndUpdate`. My query is as follows:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      filter,
      { $inc: { att1: value1 } },
      { upsert: true, new: true }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      filter,
      { $inc: { att1: value1 } },
      { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
    );
```

The reason why you get null is the default `returnOriginal:true`. If there is no match, returns null.

The documentation is rather poor respect to what it returns when no match happens. So I say "Try".